# Popover gets hidden under the nav bar in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a help button within my navbar, with a popover functionality.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="nav pull-right">
               <div class="cb_inline_block">               
                   <a class="btn btn-small cb_inline_block icon timezone_help" data-content="{% trans 'hahaha' %}" rel="popover" href="#" data-original-title="{% trans 'Time Zone' %}"><i class="icon-question-sign icon-large"></i></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $('.timezone_help').click(show_timezone_help); };

function show_timezone_help(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.timezone_help').popover('show');
}
```

But when I click on it the popover is hidden behind the nav bar.

Do I really have to set the z-index manually? That would be painful.  SUrely I must be doing something wrong. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What version of Twitter Bootstrap? I'm testing in 2.1 and it works fine for me: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/Lwpzp/). Also, if you are using 2.1, the default trigger for popovers is **click** rather than **hover**, so you can just call `$('.timezone_help').popover()` once and that'll do everything thing your current JS does.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to also share with us whatever non-Bootstrap CSS you are using in that navbar.

Comment: @merv thank you so much for your fiddle. I am using ver 2.1.1 and this might be actually the problem.  I have created a new fiddle here and copy/pasted your code in there. The buttons now appear on the very right side on nav bar (hard to scroll to). But once you click on it the tip of the arrow goes behind the nav bar!!! Seems like zindex. I also have pasted in my entire css in there.   http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/XRSFr/1/

Comment: Try data-container="body"  . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025438/bootstrap-popover-not-showing-on-top-of-all-elements

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, the answer to your question is that popovers are not intended to be used in a fixed navbar.  In the **variables.less**, you will find the following list of z-indexes:

```
// Z-index master list
// -------------------------
// Used for a bird's eye view of components dependent on the z-axis
// Try to avoid customizing these :)
@zindexDropdown:          1000;
@zindexPopover:           1010;
@zindexTooltip:           1030;
@zindexFixedNavbar:       1030;
@zindexModalBackdrop:     1040;
@zindexModal:             1050;
```

As you can see, Popovers are intended to slip beneath the fixed navbar.  However, you will notice that Tooltips will not, and you can also use `trigger: 'click'` on tooltips.

Otherwise, if you are deadset on the popover, you are going to have to manually change it's z-index.  The following will activate it and permanently change it's z-index, so you don't have to worry about doing it every time it shows, or anything like that:

```
$('.timezone_help')
  .popover({placement: "bottom"})
  .data('popover').tip()
    .css('z-index', 1030);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/qZFhC/)

---

Second, just an explanation as to why my example *seemed* to work, whereas yours didn't.

The significant point of difference between our two examples ([mmfansler JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/Lwpzp/) and [houmie JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/XRSFr/1/)) was actually not a difference between 2.1.0 and 2.1.1.  Both of them have `z-index: 1030` for fixed navbars and `z-index: 1010` for popovers (which is what your complaining about).

The real point of difference is that my 2.1.0 example is also loading the responsive code.  For some reason BootstrapCDN changed the naming convention:

- bootstrap.min.css in 2.1.0 was a combined version
- bootstrap.min.css in 2.1.1 in the non-responsive only

I suspect this is a mistake, since as of me writing this **bootstrap-combined.min.css** is also non-responsive only!

Anyway, the only difference between the two which affects the popover display is:

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: static;
}
```

This rule however, only holds for certain media queries (which of course in JSFiddle gets activated since the viewport of the render is small).

Otherwise, when the navbar isn't static, you will continue to see the popovers beneath the navbar.

You might want to keep an eye on the [BootstrapCDN Issue #41](https://github.com/netdna/bootstrap-cdn/issues/41)

Comment: +1 for this great answer. The reason I rather go with popover over the tooltip, is that on iPads you don't really have a cursor and tooltip becomes useless.  While a popover is very much iPad-ish. :)  For now since I have only one opoover on nav bar, I have cheated to make it work by putting this into my css: `.popover{ z-index: 1055; }`. Your solution seems more clever though. Regarding the BootstrapCDN, good catch. But thats only the online version correct? The downloaded bootstrap files aren't affected, correct?

Comment: If you use `.tooltip({trigger: "click"})` it will use clicks instead of hover, solving your touch interface issue. The BootstrapCDN issue does not affect the bootstrap downloads.  The way I elected to change the z-index in my example was in order to change it for only that one popover, as I personally wouldn't want to change the default for *all* popovers.  Finally, why 1055? Do you really want the popover to be on top of any modals?

Comment: You are right, 1030 is a better value. And thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I decided as follow:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  z-index:1061;
}
```

Popovers default to index 1060, so anything that is above 1060 is positioned over Popovers

Sory for the wrong English I'm Brasilian and I am using Google Translate

Answer (score 0):

set these properties:

```
data-container="body" style="z-index:1000; position:relative"
```

z-index should be max limit.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to set the container of my popover to **body** and the z-index

```
$().popover({container: 'body'})
```