# bootstrap popover not showing on top of all elements

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm working on a bootstrap site and after updating to bootstrap 2.2 from 2.0 everything worked except the popover.

The popovers still show up fine, but they don't show up on top of all other elements.

```
<div> // this sits on top of the popover. this did not happen before cleaning up scripts.
     <div>  //popover shows on top of this
          <div> //popover shows on top of this
               //link here with popover in it.
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have any idea on why the behavior of the popover changed, or how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I found my solution with this script.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64905483/6128573

Answer (score 374, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by setting `data-container="body"` on the html element

*`HTML` example:*

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" title="first tooltip">
    hover over me
</a>
```

*`JavaScript` example:*

```
$('your element').tooltip({ container: 'body' })
```

Discovered from this link: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5889

Comment: This really helped. 

I made the following change in the popover initialization and it worked:

$('#element').popover({
        container: 'body',
        //other parameters
});

Comment: I got a 404 for that link. Update, please?

Comment: @NoBrainer
Can't seem to find a new link for it, but adding data-container="body" to the html element should work, or passing in container: 'body' through javascript should also work

Comment: adding data-container="body" seems to work in bootstrap 3 as well for tooltips, when they are for example in overflow

Comment: While this sorts out the original z-index issue, the popover doesn't stick with the original trigger element once you start dragging things around the screen, zooming in or out, or resizing the window. Looking for a better answer for this myself.

Comment: @Kyle this did fxed the issue for me on desktop browsers and mobile, but i am stil facing the issue with IPad Air, any suggestion why its not working there?

Comment: @AlpanaChauhan what version of bootstrap are you using? can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: In my case I needed it to show above a chatbox. Changing 'body' to the class name of my chat window, fixed the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: Valid for bootstrap tooltips too `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body' })`

Answer (score 46):

This is Working for me

```
$().popover({container: 'body'})
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. its important to know what value needs to be set for "container" property. Just for reference, contents copied from bootstrap popovers document - "When you have some styles on a parent element that interfere with a popover, you’ll want to specify a custom container so that the popover’s HTML appears within that element instead."

Answer (score 26):

I just had a situation that was similar to this, involving the DataTables JQuery library with scrolling enabled.

What turned out to be had nothing to do with Z-indices, but with one of the enclosing divs having the CSS overflow property set as hidden.

I fixed it by adding an event to my element triggering the popover which also changed the overflow property of the responsible div to visible.

Comment: You're a life saver!! All the answers I read were about z-index and to be honest it was the only thing that made sense for me, but at the end, none of the suggestions worked until I decided to try your z-index unrelated answer! Thanx

Answer (score 17):

The most probable cause is that the content displaying over the popover has a higher `z-index`. Without the precise code/style, I can offer two options :

You should try pinpointing the exact elements with a web inspector (usually F12 on your favorite browser) and check their actual `z-index`.

If you find this value, you can set it **lower than the popover** which is [`z-index: 1010;` by default](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.2/less/variables.less#L145)

---

Or the other approach, not as good, would be to increase the `z-index` of the popover. You can do that either with the `@zindexPopover` in the Less files or directly by overriding

```css
.popover {
    z-index: 1010; /* A value higher than 1010 that solves the problem */
}
```

---

If you can't find a solution, you should try reproducing the bug in something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/vdWDQ/) - you will probably resolve the problem while trying to get the bug.

Comment: I will try to make a jsfiddle and post back if i do not find it, but i tried making the popover a z-index of 9999 with no luck.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the default z-index value of the popover.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar issue with 2 fixed elements - even though the z-index heirachy was correct, the bootstrap tooltip was hidden behind the one element wth a lower z-index.

Adding `data-container="body"` resolved the issue and now works as expected.

Answer (score 9):

If data-container="body" not works than try other two properties:

```
data-container="body" style="z-index:1000; position:relative"
```

z-index should be max limit.

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="testDiv">
<a tabindex = "-1" id="testPop" title="stuff" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-container=".testDiv">
 <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>

</div>
```

Above answers were helpful as setting value in data-container did the job but if i set data-container="body" then it doesn't align properly in my case. So i specified the class of the parent div of popover and it worked fine.

html

data-container=".testDiv"

js

$("#testPop").popover({container: '.testDiv'})

Answer (score 2):

This best solution if you are using angular uib-bootsrap is to Use dependency injection for $uibTooltipProvider, you can change the way tooltips and popovers behave by default for all the tooltips.

```
$uibTooltipProvider.options({
  appendToBody: true
});
```

**$uibTooltipProvider**
Through the $uibTooltipProvider, you can change the way tooltips and popovers behave by default; the attributes above always take precedence. The following methods are available:

**setTriggers**(obj) (Example: { 'openTrigger': 'closeTrigger' }) - Extends the default trigger mappings mentioned above with mappings of your own.

**options**(obj) - Provide a set of defaults for certain tooltip and popover attributes. Currently supports the ones with the C badge.

Answer (score 2):

Many years later, but like me, others may search for this. All updates taking into consideration, all this can be solved with correct initialization options, in JavaScript.

```
$('.tip').tooltip({
    boundary: 'viewport',
    placement: 'top',
    container:'body',
    sanitize: true,
    appendToBody: true
});
```

Those settings solved all may issues. I had tooltips flickering, showing corectly only for half of the items on page, jumping from top to left continously, all kinds of wierdness. But with those settings everything is solved. Hope it help anyone looking.

Comment: and yes it happened.. I just copied and pasted and it solved the problems I was having with placing the popover on top... container: body didn't work, changing the styles of anything closely related didn't work.. I don't what's the magic here and didn't have time to find out but it just worked :) thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        boundary: 'viewport',
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            let content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
            return $(content).html();
        }
    });,



`placement`: 'top',
`boundary`: 'viewport'
both needed
```

Answer (score 1):

giving my 2 cents,
My issue was NOT the container nor the z-index like other solution above, but the opacity set in a transition.

```
.popover{opacity:1}
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just using

```
$().popover({container: 'body'})
```

could be not enough when displaying popover over a BootstrapDialog modal, which also uses body as container and has a higher z-index.

I come with this fix which uses internals of Bootstrap3 (may not work with 2.x / 4.x) but most of modern Bootstrap installations are 3.x.

```
self.$anchor.on('shown.bs.popover', function(ev) {
    var tipCSS = self.$anchor.data('tipCSS');
    if (tipCSS !== undefined) {
        self.$anchor.data('bs.popover').$tip.css(tipCSS);
    }
    // ...
});
```

Such way different popovers may have different z-index, some are under BootstrapDialog modal, while another ones are over it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use the popover template option and add my own css class to the template html:

```
        $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover(
          {
            container: 'body',
            template: '<div class="popover top-modal" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
       });
```

Css:

```
.top-modal {
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with `data-container="body"` and `z-index`:

```html
<div class="button btn-align"
     data-container="body"  
     data-toggle="popover"
     data-placement="top"
     title="Top"
     data-trigger="hover"
     data-title-backcolor="#fff"
     data-content="A top aligned popover is a really boring thing in the real life."
>Top</div>
```

```css
.ggpopover.in {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have some styles on a parent element that interfere with a popover, you’ll want to specify a custom container so that the popover’s HTML appears within that element instead.

For instance say the parent for a popover is body then you can use.

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body"> Popover One </a>
```

Other case might be when popover is placed inside some other element and you want to show popover over that element, then you'll need to specify that element in data-container.
ex: Suppose, we have popover inside a bootstrap modal with id as 'modal-two', then you'll need to set 'data-container' to 'modal-two'.

```
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="#modal-two"> Popover Two </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

It could have to do with the z-index master list on variables.less. In general, be sure that your variables.less file is correct and up-to-date.