# Fullcalendar Rendering Popover/Tooltip issue

Tags: fullcalendar

I have imported fullcalendar plugin , and i am trying to modify the view by adding popover/tooltip on selected events.
    But popovers with large content  are partially hidden.
Please refer to the attached image for better understanding.

I have appended this code to get the desired effect.
Javscript:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
        eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {         
        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        $(this).find(".fc-content").attr({"data-toggle":"popover","title":calEvent.title,"data-content":calEvent.title});
        $(this).find(".fc-content").click(function(){$(this).popover('show');},function(){$(this).popover('hide');});
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bootstrap question more than a fullCalendar one. 
As you can see here: [Bootstrap popover not showing on top of all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025438/bootstrap-popover-not-showing-on-top-of-all-elements)
Just add to .attr "data-container": "body".

So:

```
$(this).find(".fc-content").attr({"data-toggle":"popover","title":calEvent.title,"data-content":calEvent.title});
```

Should be:

```
$(this).find(".fc-content").attr({"data-toggle":"popover","title":calEvent.title,"data-content":calEvent.title, "data-container": "body"});
```

Comment: But then if the calendar is scrolled or resized, the popover is not re-positioned along with the event and looks buggy.