# Top of bootstrap popover being cut off within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table full of buttons that generates popovers to the left and the table is within an accordion. The problem is when if the popover is generated from the top of the table, the popover  gets cut off. How would I manually position the popover by pixel-still on the left, or just get it to appear on top(outside the div).

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Br4Zg/1115/)

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
       <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class = "testTable">
            <table class = "table table-striped">
            <tr><td>Test1</td>
            <td>         
                <div class = "td-container">
                    <div class ="btn-group btn-broup-sm">
                        <button id="elem" class="btn btn-danger" data-trigger="click">
                            Click for popover</button>
                    </div></div></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test3</td>
                <td>Test3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>Test4</td>
                <td>Test5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

         <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Test text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.well {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.testTable{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

table{
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#elem').popover({placement:"left",
                    container:".td-container",
                    html: true,
                    title: "Test popover",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quism."});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the container as body

```
$('#elem').popover({placement:"left",
                    container:"body",
                    html: true,
                        title: "Test popover",
                        content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quism."});
```

Comment: If I add it to the body, the popover won't scroll along with the table. It stays fixed to the body

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the container using the data-container attribute or do it in JavaScript.

```
$('#elem').popover({placement:"left",
                    container:".td-container",
                    html: true,
                    title: "Test popover",
                    container: "body",
                    content:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quism."});
```

Discovered from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15981951/2527231

Comment: If I add it to the body, the popover won't scroll along with the table. It stays fixed to the body.