# bootstrap tooltip not showing context color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I had a problem where my tooltips where not showing on top of my datatable.
I solved this by adding `data-container='body'` as an attribute (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025438/bootstrap-popover-not-showing-on-top-of-all-elements)) which now shows the full tooltip but creates a new problem; it removes the context of the tooltip.

As example:

```
<div class="text-info tooltip-info" 
     data-rel="tooltip" 
     data-html="true" 
     data-original-title="     
       <div class=&quot;text-left&quot;>         
          <i><b>Commercial decision:</b> <br> </i> <br>          
          <i><b>Technical decision:</b> <br> </i> <br>       
          <i><b>Overall decision:</b> <br> </i>     
       </div>" 
     style="font-weight: bold;overflow: auto;">
     Pending
</div>
```

yields:

[image]

which is not shown on top of the datatable but does have the correct context.

Adding `data-container='body'` yields:

[image]

which display correctly but doesn't show any context.

How do i display the tooltip correctly while retaining the context i want?

Comment: Test case would greatly increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Here what contexts are missing that you have been looking for?

Comment: As @ochi mentioned, a fiddle would be useful. Have you tried inspecting the tooltip in the browser console (right click on it then inspect) to see which classes the different tooltips gain with the different container options you have set. From there, you should be able to see why the colour is not what you expect, and update your CSS from there (or add classes dynamically to the tooltip).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will fix your issue. if not then I would like to ask your code too. it's easy to inspect then.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```css
.parent-container {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-container"><div class="" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" data-container=".parent-container" data-html="true" title="     
       <div class=&quot;text-left&quot;>         
          <i><b>Commercial decision:</b> <br> </i> <br>          
          <i><b>Technical decision:</b> <br> </i> <br>       
          <i><b>Overall decision:</b> <br> </i>     
       </div>" 
     style="font-weight: bold;overflow: auto;">
  Pendings
</div></div>
```