# How to show popover that is hiding behind navbar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and Angular. In my webpage there is a button and i am providing a popover for a span like this

```
<span popover="Download Project History" popover-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="top" style="padding: 5px" translate="DOWNLOAD">DOWNLOAD</span>
```

But its getting hidden under navbar.

Based on my googling i found to provide data-container="body" in the html element. But its not working too.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a demo?

Comment: A screenshot??? how can i share a screenshot with you??

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had a similar problem where the popover was hidden behind overflow content and adding the following attribute fixed it:

```
popover-append-to-body="true"
```

Comment: Worked like a Charm ,Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```
tooltip-append-to-body="true"
```

attaches the tooltip to the body and makes it visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `z-index` value, you can have a look for the default values (for navbar and popover) in original Bootstrap's CSS file. In my case this helped:

```
.popover {

    /* just in case it would overlap with fixed navbar, then show this over the navbar. Original value 1010, value for navbar is 1030 */

    z-index: 1030;

}
```

Comment: So provide the z-index for the nav bar rt?

Comment: Are you loading this custom CSS **after** the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12341226/1464298) is nice ST answer describing also possible issue with responsive code

Comment: I added it in the html control itself. Will try in the script and check